# Using CiviCRM to track number of signatures collected for ballot initiative

Tags: custom-fields, civivolunteer

Anyone have any advice how I might keep track of how many signatures are gathered through our volunteer tabling and events to qualify a ballot measure?  We need to collect 5000 wet signatures for a ballot initiative and are using CiviVolunteer running on Wordpress to track all the events we are tabling at and get our volunteers to staff them. I am looking for a way to report and track the outcome of each event by entering the total number of wet signatures gathered so we have a running total in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom field to the Event - then you can enter the numbers for each event in to that field. Then you should be able to spit out a Report based on Events.

If you don't want the field showing on the event info page, then set custom field not to be 'is public'

Comment: I did this and it showed up on the event public form. I went to settings for custom field and unchecked Is this field public? Now I see it on the backend but not on the public form. Works perfect. @petednz thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i added that helpful advice to the Answer - perhaps you can 'accept' it now?